# How to extract only a portion of each element in a list?

Tags: python, list

I want to Extract `id` from list. `id` is auto generated.

```
BOOKS[
  {
    'id':'12345edfer8498erf84f8',
    'name':'Mr.k'
  }
]
```

How to select only `id`?

```
print(BOOKS['id'])
```

Is not working.

Example of what I want:

```
print(BOOKS['id'])
```

Output:

```
id:12345edfer8498erf84f8
```

Comment: `BOOKS` is a list. You should access the first element in it: `BOOKS[0]['id']`.

Comment: `BOOKS[0]['id']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `books[0]['id']`:

```
books = [
  {
    'id': '12345edfer8498erf84f8',
    'name': 'Mr.k'
  }
]

print(books[0]['id']) # output 12345edfer8498erf84f8
```

Answer (score 1):

It's at the index `0`. Hence access it like:

`BOOKS[0]['id']`